# gridview sort not working for numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sorting

I have implemented the sort function in  my codebehind, it works fine with words but not with numbers...
eg

```
4,693 
1,494  
23
```

when i sort this i get

```
> 1,494
> 23
> 4,693
```

so this means its just checking the first number....

my code for sort is:

```
 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;

            if (dt != null)
            {

                //Sort the data.
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
                GridView1.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Reports1mod.aspx");
        }

    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {
        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }
```

Comment: It's probably because the tables contains strings, not integers.

Comment: How have you populated the field... Have you populated as numbers with dataformat string or you converted the number to string to add commas and then populated the Grid View Column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said, have you bound the column to a string to get those commas?

You should let the column bind to the int value, and set the DataFormatString to "{0:N}" for numeric with group separator. (See [BoundField.DataFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

This happens when sorting *numbers as strings*.

It sorts string *left-to-right*, which in your case **2 in 23 is before 4**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's sorting the numbers as strings - ie, in alphabetical order rather than numerical order. I can't quite see where your actual column / value is in there, could you surround it with some sort of a cast / convert to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too after referring to the MSDN page for a quick tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting(v=vs.110).aspx

All you have to do is specify the type for the TableData Column with the 2nd parameter:

```
   //To allow sorting numerically, add type param to column
   table1.Columns.Add("GridTest ID", typeof(Int32));
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else.