# numbers/decimals not sorting in radgrid

Tags: vb.net, sorting, visual-studio-2012, numbers, decimal

Hi I am not able to sort a column that contains decimals in a radgrid. When I sort, it only sorts by first number, like if sorting a string.

Ex: 1000, 12, 1300, 2189, 20

Instead of sorting like this:

12, 20, 1000, 1300, 2189

I am using EF4 and working with VS2012 in vb.net.

Any suggestions? this is my column:

Comment: Are you SURE that they aren't strings?  VB is notorious for casting things without the programmer even knowing.  Try explicitly casting your values from EF into integers or doubles and see if it changes.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, applying any formatting to those numbers which may be causing them to cast to a string? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1928084/211627

Comment: Yes I went through every variable and made sure it was reading it as a decimal. This is my aspx for it: '<telerik:GridBoundColumn  DataField="Voltage" HeaderText="Voltage" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="Voltage"  DataType="System.decimal"  UniqueName="Voltage">
 </telerik:GridBoundColumn>'